# Issue while debugging dspace 6.0 jspui application on intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, solr, tomcat7, dspace

I have tried to configure dspace 6.0 on Intellij .But while debugging application I am getting below error.I think while configuring tomcat 7  on Intellij **dspace-dir** value is overridden.
Please suggest what change i need to make in configuration.

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.96/bin/$%7Bdspace.dir%7D/config/log4j-solr.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.96\bin\${dspace.dir}\config\log4j-solr.properties (The system cannot find the path specified
```

)

Reference link :
IntelliJ IDEA 13 setup for DSpace development on Mac OS XIntelliJ IDEA 13 setup for DSpace development on Mac OS X
https://youtu.be/mrLl1qPsy6I

Comment: Where do you see this error? notice the `${dspace.dir}` placeholder in the log file path URL. It may cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the log snippet you posted comes from the tomcat or DSpace log, when trying to start up DSpace, the causes could be:

- dspace.dir value not filled out
- maven or ant commando's not executed successfully. They have to be completed before starting up DSpace will work.